# how do I ensure good logging when closing my application?

Tags: c#, finalizer

I have a class, Foo, that is a wrapper for a SerialPort Object. It also contains a Log class, that i use to both display messages and save them to a file.

Foo listens to the ports events, and handles them through a thread, where all the logging operations happen.

When I close my application, I want to make sure that all the outbound messages are sent, and that all the inbound messages are handled and logged.

Right now, ~Log closes the log file, and I call the logging functions one last time in the threads ThreadAbortException code, and abort the tread from ~foo(), but I have learned that Finalizer call order is not guaranteed, which reeks of nullpointerException if my log object is finalized before Foo.

Am I right to be worried? what would be the right way to proceed?

Comment: Multitasking and in particular Threading is notorious for swallowing exceptions. So you are right to be worried | The obvious way to avoid waiting for the finalizers, is to call dispose. On the one hand, if you need one the Finalizer for your class should be the first thing you write for the Dispose pattern. On the other, it should be the kind of code that should never be run in the first place. It is a fallback, a safety net - not the first choice.

Comment: I asume you got some kind of loop that keeps polling for messages. It is the usual pattern. If so, create the instance before the loop. Wait for a cleaned cache after the loop. Then dispose. | It is a bit of a tricky situation, as you need to catch Exogenous and vexing excptions in the loop, but also need to catch the more serious ones outside the loop. One `catch(exception)` that does nothing but logging and rethrowing per thread is the way to go.

Comment: As for general rules on exception handling, here are two articles on the mater I link often wich have helped a lot of people: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: The easiest way to ensure this is to simply not allow your application to exit before you're done. "Closing" is a cooperative process in almost all cases -- a signal is sent, you do processing, and when all threads of the process have finished, it's considered done. Trying to rely on finalizers for this is doomed to failure -- if you can't guarantee clean shutdown to the point where you are relying on the finalizers to save your bacon, you're almost certainly going to have trouble with the finalizers not running either. And, of course, doing non-trivial things from finalizers is Bad.

Comment: All this talk of "aborting threads" is also something that should make you very nervous. Strive to never have any thread aborted for any reason, and certainly don't abort threads yourself. Threads should exit cleanly, when a flag/event is set that we're exiting. It is easy, tempting and wrong to interrupt and cancel threads to do the exit logic.